# Удаление виджета из QLayout

Tags: qt, qtcreator, виджет, qwidget

У меня есть layout куда я добавляю виджеты, я хотел бы удалять первый вошедший виджет и добавлять новый, но у меня не получается его удалить

```
customWidget *new_widget = new customWidget;
if(counter == 3)
{
    QLayoutItem *item = ui->displayLayout->takeAt(0);
    delete item->widget();
    delete item;
    counter = 0;
}
ui->displayLayout->addWidget(new_widget);
counter++;
```

Comment: Почему вы решили, что не получается?

Comment: Вы правы, оно работает, мой затуп, я счётчик обнулял, и добавлялись новые, а я и не замечал.
Спасибо за замечание!